# How to programmatically calculate the difference between a pair of variables using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a tibble like the following:

```
tib <- tribble(~id, ~var1_countrya, ~var2_countrya, ~var1_countryb, ~var2_countryb,
1, 1, 2, 1, 2,
2, 5, 3, 1, 3,
3, 6, 3, 1, 3
)
```

I'd like to create new columns `delta_countrya = var2_countrya - var1_countrya` and `delta_countryb = var2_countryb - var2_countryb` by selecting the pairs of variables using a regex and dplyr pipes. The final tibble should look like this

```
id var1_countrya var2_countrya delta_countrya var1_countryb var2_countryb delta_countryb
1             1             2              1             1             2              1
2             5             3             -2             1             3              2
3             6             3             -3             1             3              2
```

I've struggled to even set up the mutate clause in a way it creates multiple new variables, let alone finding the pairs of variables I'm looking for and taking the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your example, you could convert your columns to variables, split the columns so the var and the country are separate, then re-combine so the different vars are in columns, and finally calculate your delta

```
library(dplyr) 
tib <- tribble(~id, ~var1_countrya, ~var2_countrya, ~var1_countryb, ~var2_countryb,
1, 1, 2, 1, 2,
2, 5, 3, 1, 3,
3, 6, 3, 1, 3
)  # your code had an error, need to replace ')' with comma

tib2 = tib %>%
      pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "var") %>%
      separate(var, c("Var", "Country")) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = Var) %>%
      mutate(Delta = var2-var1)
tib2
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#      id Country   var1  var2 Delta
#    <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 countrya     1     2     1
# 2     1 countryb     1     2     1
# 3     2 countrya     5     3    -2
# 4     2 countryb     1     3     2
# 5     3 countrya     6     3    -3
# 6     3 countryb     1     3     2
```

Comment: Great, this worked like a charm. Obviously, we would then need to pivot_wider to get the final tibble.

Answer (score 2):

`base`

```
tib[paste0("delta_country", letters[1:2])] <- tib[paste0("var2_country", letters[1:2])] - tib[paste0("var1_country", letters[1:2])]
    #      id var1_countrya var2_countrya var1_countryb var2_countryb delta_countrya delta_countryb
    #   <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
    # 1     1             1             2             1             2              1              1
    # 2     2             5             3             1             3             -2              2
    # 3     3             6             3             1             3             -3              2
```

---

`tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
tib[paste0("delta_country", letters[1:2])] <- map2(tib %>% select(starts_with("var2_country")), tib %>% select(starts_with("var1_country")),
                                     ~.x - .y)
tib
# #      id var1_countrya var2_countrya var1_countryb var2_countryb delta_countrya delta_countryb
# #   <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
# # 1     1             1             2             1             2              1              1
# # 2     2             5             3             1             3             -2              2
# # 3     3             6             3             1             3             -3              2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also take advantage of `base::Reduce` here:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) {
  cbind(x, x[, y] - x[, y - 1])
}, seq(1, ncol(tib), 2)[-1], init = tib) |>
  setNames(c(names(tib), paste0("delta_country", unique(gsub(".*([[:alpha:]]$)", "\\1", names(tib)[-1])))))

  id var1_countrya var2_countrya var1_countryb var2_countryb delta_countrya delta_countryb
1  1             1             2             1             2              1              1
2  2             5             3             1             3             -2              2
3  3             6             3             1             3             -3              2
```