# create variables with map2 and qnorm

Tags: r, purrr

Given:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(est = c(1.36, -0.03),
                 std = c(0.16, 0.18))
df
#     est  std
# 1  1.36 0.16
# 2 -0.03 0.18
```

I want to do the following:

```
exp(df[1, 1] + qnorm(c( 0.025, 0.5, 0.975))*df[1, 2])
# [1] 2.847398 3.896193 5.331295
exp(df[2, 1] + qnorm(c( 0.025, 0.5, 0.975))*df[2, 2])
# [1] 0.6819537 0.9704455 1.3809802
```

To end up with the following `df`:

```
df_final
#     est  std        or        ll       ul
# 1  1.36 0.16 2.8473980 3.8961930 5.331295
# 2 -0.03 0.18 0.6819537 0.9704455 1.380980
```

I am not sure why this won't work:

```
df[c("or", "ll", "ul")] <- map2(df %>% select(est),
                               df %>% select(std), ~ exp(.x + qnorm(c( 0.025, 0.5, 0.975))*.y))
```

any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
pmap_dfr(df, ~ exp(..1 + qnorm(c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975)) * ..2) %>% 
        as.list %>% 
        setNames(c('or', 'll', 'ul'))) %>% 
  bind_cols(df, .)
```

-output

```
  est  std        or        ll       ul
1  1.36 0.16 2.8473985 3.8961933 5.331295
2 -0.03 0.18 0.6819537 0.9704455 1.380980
```

---

In the OP's post, it is `select`ing the column, which is still a `data.frame/tibble` with single column.  Instead it should be extracted as a `vector` i.e. with `pull`.  When we have a `data.frame`, the unit for looping is column and not rows i.e.

```
df[c("or", "ll", "ul") <-  map2(df %>% pull(est),
                               df %>% pull(std), 
     ~ exp(.x + qnorm(c( 0.025, 0.5, 0.975))*.y)) %>% 
       invoke(rbind, .)
```

---

Or may use `dapply`

```
library(collapse)
f1 <- function(x) setNames(exp(x[1] + 
    qnorm(c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975)) * x[2]), c('or', 'll', 'ul'))
cbind(df, dapply(df, MARGIN = 1, f1))
  est  std        or        ll       ul
1  1.36 0.16 2.8473985 3.8961933 5.331295
2 -0.03 0.18 0.6819537 0.9704455 1.380980
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't think I need `pull` though, as I didnt do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69379945/4083743

Comment: @user63230 When you do `map(df, ~ .x)` the unit is a column thus it loop over the column..  With `map2`, you need both 'est', 'std' for each corresponding row

Comment: @user63230 that was a different case, when you have more than one column and want to apply the function across those corresponding columns.  Here, your aim is not to apply the function on each column as a whole, but on the rows

Answer (score 1):

in base R you could use:

```
a <- exp(df[[1]] + t(qnorm(c( 0.025, 0.5, 0.975)) %o% df[[2]])) 
cbind(df, setNames(data.frame(a),c('or', 'll', 'ul')))

    est  std        or        ll       ul
1  1.36 0.16 2.8473985 3.8961933 5.331295
2 -0.03 0.18 0.6819537 0.9704455 1.380980
```